# SSH, Webmin, etc. stopped working after CPU upgrade

Tags: upgrade, ssh, cpu

I upgraded the CPU in my home server: i3-3220T -> E3-1265L V2. The upgrade was succesfull, the server started proerly, however some services stopped working.
I cannot use SSH now. I checked the service is running on the server. I cannot load the page of webmin running on the server on my desktop PC, and have the same issue on localhost.
The new CPU supports AES-NI, the old one did not.

What could I do?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: run ssh in verbose mode by giving it parm -vv   as in `ssh -vv foo@bar` to see why ssh fails ... on your machine where you issue ssh from issue ... `ssh-add -l` to list keys may be you just need to add your key or use  `ssh -i ~/.ssh/mykeyname  --vv foo@bar`

Comment: The desktop PC runs Windows10 and I use PuTTY for SSH.

Comment: your ssh client must have a verbose mode

Comment: It has logging mode, but all I got: "Connection timed out."

Answer (score 0):

You are on windows however it must have similar tools to these ubuntu desktop commands ... issue this to view all IP visible maybe your ubuntu server IP address changed

```
sudo apt-get install arp-scan
sudo arp-scan
```

top line of output will show your network interface something like

```
Interface: wlp2s0, datalink type: EN10MB (Ethernet)
```

lets call it XXXXXX (its possibly wlp2s0)  now use that

```
sudo arp-scan -I XXXXXX -l
```

in my case I use

```
sudo arp-scan   -I wlp2s0  -l
```

its output is

```
Interface: wlp2s0, datalink type: EN10MB (Ethernet)
Starting arp-scan 1.9.5 with 256 hosts (https://github.com/royhills/arp-scan)
192.168.1.1 00:23:69:9e:ae:7d   Cisco-Linksys, LLC
192.168.1.101   94:0e:6b:07:43:d5   (Unknown)
192.168.1.104   f4:8c:50:9f:e0:34   (Unknown)

3 packets received by filter, 0 packets dropped by kernel
Ending arp-scan 1.9.5: 256 hosts scanned in 2.574 seconds (99.46 hosts/sec). 3 responded
```

What we are doing here is listing all IP visible to your laptop which should list your ubuntu server ... assure the IP listed is the one you are ssh into perhaps it got a new IP

Comment: Hi,
the IP address is the same, I have samba service on the server, and it's running properly. I can reach my folders using the server's IP address.
And the webmin fails to load on localhost (on the server), as well.
I think the issue is caused somehow by the SSL service. The new CPU supports AES-NI. The server says `(rdrand) Intel RDRAND engine` if I check the openssl engine, and the internet says it should be
`(aesni) Intel AES-NI engine`.

Comment: Ok, your suggestion partially helped. I had another network issue, independent from the CPU upgrade. It just happened at the same time.
So the SSH is working now, but still have problems with webmin.

Comment: Purged and reinstalled webmin. Working now. Do not know what happened to it.

Comment: @FerencNémeth sweet - have fun